# Arguments for Function in register_activation_hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function I am trying to use when I activate the plugin.

```
function function_name( $argument_1, $argument_2) { ... }
```

The `register_activation_hook` requires the function to be entered as followed

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'function_name' );
```

**How do I add arguments to the function?**

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> register_activation_hook( string $file, callable $function )

so if the `$function` must be a callable you can inject $args like this:

```
$args = ['Hello','World']
register_activation_hook( __FILE__,function()use($args){  });
```

also you can do

```
$args = ['Hello','World']
register_activation_hook( __FILE__,function()use($args){ 
   return function_name( $args[0], $args[1]);       
});
```